# APK installation on diff versions of OS in android

Tags: android, apk

I have a apk of android 2.3v and i need to install it on the android 2.2v mobile..

will it works on the android 2.2 mobile.plz tell me as soon as possible

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this apk are build by you or download ?

Comment: if this apk is genrated by you then you can change its version and run in 2.2 otherwise,android strictly prohibited to load 2.3v to 2.2

Answer (score 0):

You follow following steps:--

1. go to manifest file and change the min. sdk
   like   `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />`
   2 run the app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the minSdkVersion in the manifest file maximum to the 2.2's API level. And it will run without problem (if there aren't any problem with your code).